Concave maximization over $d$-dimensional simplex.
Can either an analytic solution or the dual be characterized for the following concave maximization:
$v:= \underset{w \in \Delta_d}{\max} \sum^{d}_{i=1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+b_i/w_i}}$
where $\Delta_d$ denotes the $d-$ dimensional simplex and $b_i>0$, $\forall i \in [d]$?
Tight upper and lower bounds on the value $v$ is also useful. It is straightforward by considering the fact that $0 \leq w_i \leq 1$ to derive the following upper and lower bounds for $v$:
$\sqrt{\sum^{d}_{i=1}\frac{1}{b_i}} \geq v \geq \sqrt{\sum^{d}_{i=1}\frac{1}{1+b_i}}$.
These bounds suggest that $v \sim \sqrt{\sum^{d}_{i=1}\frac{1}{b_i}}$ whenever $b_i >> 1$ for all $i$. It will be helpful to get bounds that are tight when $b_i$ are relatively smaller.

have you tried to solve the KKT system?

It seems complicated to resolve the KKT system however I was able to get a one dimensional dual problem by using the more general fenchel duality. The key point is that fenchel duality allows one extra freedom that lagrangean duality does not. The idea is to decompose the constraints into product set and it's intersection with the simplex.
